# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference Error When Opening Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I got the following error when Trying to Open a Form in Visual Basic

```
Error   1   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.  c:\users\alex96\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Home Work Calendar\Home Work Calendar\StartUp.vb  25  13  Home Work Calendar
```

and Here is the code I used to open the form (the not working line)

```
 frmCourses.Show()
```

Normally, this would work, but now it isn't and I don't think I did anything different when creating the other form

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: It appears that you're trying to use the default instance but are unable to.  Have you added a constructor with one or more parameters to that frmCourses class?  If so then that would be the issue.  Obviously you're not passing any arguments when implicitly creating the default instance so it requires a parameterless constructor.  If that's not it, have you done anything else to that form class that could be considered out of the ordinary?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to be using default instance? It's a good practice to avoid it, because it's ambiguous with shared calls, and you have less control, compared to manual instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of the object.

```
Dim xForm as new frmCourses
xForm.Show
```