# what is the different in form2.Close() and Form3.ActiveForm.Close() in VB

Tags: vb.net

what is the different in Close() and ActiveForm.Close() in VB?

```
    form2.ActiveForm.Close()         [ currently at Form 3 ]

    form1.Close()
```

(different) form1.Close()

question: In Form 1 and Form 2, I can use obj/Form1.Close() and obj2/Form2.Close() without problem, In both form i can do, vise versa.

However, when it comes to Form 3, at this point i only can set Form1.close , But Form2. I had to use form2.ActiveForm.Close().
Why is this happening?

I would like to know what is the real meaning of using

Form.Close()    &       Form.ActiveForm.Close()

I had searched and failed to understand in every site. would anyone kindly explain?
is it Obj/form.ActiveForm.Close() meant => Close the current Active Obj/Form???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An active form is the form with the input focus. A form that is not visible cannot be the active form. The simplest way to activate a visible form is to click it or use an appropriate keyboard combination.
I found this useful article about active forms [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Please go through that first.

Form.ActiveForm.Close() is hence used for closing an active form.

Like for example say you have an application with multiple forms and you want to close the active form, then you should be using an `activeform.close()`.
The `close()` or `me.close()` would only close the form which contains the statement rather than the active form.

Some more useful information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977217%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: so for example,

at form 2:
Hide()

^ this meant that form 2 is not an active form correct?
i see. active form is any form that is visible.

is there anyway, by any chance i can bring up the Form2 that is in Hide mode? from From 3?
I have been looking around. hmm think i may have to make a new topic for this?

Comment: When the Close method is called on a Form displayed as a modeless window, you cannot call the Show method to make the form visible, because the form's resources have already been released. To hide a form and then make it visible, use the Control.Hide method.

After you've hidden a form, you'll eventually want to make it visible again by using the Show command, such as:

FormName.Show()

Comment: active form is a form that currently that is receiving the input, to be precise. The easiest way to make a form active is to click on it. You can find useful information from the links I have attached in the answer.

Comment: ^ dear sir, Yes, i had try to do Form2.Show().
However, the system inform me " Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference ".

I this project i am doing, I use pass information from 1 form to another. From Form1 - 3 i passed the information.

The problem now is that from Form3 i would like to redisplay the Form2 (which is in Hide mode). but it do not allow me to. so far i see is that i can only type the code Form2.ActiveForm.Show().

am sorry for my long message. did really hope for help cause i can't find solution on the net. could be i fail to ask to make a hit on google

Comment: not really sure if this would help but did you try these links??
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwhc0d0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
and 
here's an answer to some other question apparently with the same error message.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126288/reference-to-a-non-shared-member-requires-an-object-reference-error-when-opening

Comment: ^ i had check the link. is true that i have create a New constructor with parameter to pass value between Forms.
so I suppose there is no other way but for me to create an instant/Obj of Form3 with parameter New constructor.

in order to call back the form. -_- guess more memory usage. cause the Form 2 is in Hide mode.
guess i'll try it.;

Comment: More memory usage it is then.

Comment: Dear Sir You_Shall_Not_Pass,

thanks for your guidance thus far, maybe i shouldn't have wasted my time and do it.
I have thought of this method in the beginning, but was hoping a better option.
still it give a great learning experience. you assist is greatly appreciated. thank you so much for your help.