# how to re-display form2 in hide mode from Form3?

Tags: vb.net

```
        form2.Hide()         [ currently at Form 3 ]

        form1.Close()
```

(different) form1.Close()

is there anyway, by any chance i can bring up the Form2 that is in Hide mode? from From 3? I have been looking around.

i had try to do Form2.Show(). However, the system inform me " Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference ".
This project i am doing, I use pass information from 1 form to another.

From Form1 - 3  passing info the information have no prob. The problem now is that from Form3 i would like to re-display the Form2 (which is in Hide mode). but it do not allow me to do so. so far i see is that i can only type the code Form2.ActiveForm.Show(). am sorry for my long message. did really hope for help cause i can't find solution on the net. could be i fail to ask to make a hit on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer so far can be found on this link given. please read through the commend for your details.

[what is the different in form2.Close() and Form3.ActiveForm.Close() in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312906/what-is-the-different-in-form2-close-and-form3-activeform-close-in-vb/28313769?noredirect=1#comment44979087_28313769)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the best solution but if I understand you right.
If you were to have a "Globals" Module and add form2 as a variable in there:

```
 Public Form2 As New Form2
```

You would then be able to control it from other forms without it becoming invalid e.g.

```
Global.Form2.Hide
Global.Form2.Show
```

And even modify the controls and values inside it from other forms:

```
Global.Form2.ThisLabel.Text = "TEXT"
```

This means form3 can have full control over your "form2" even while its hidden.

Comment: actually, I have this parameterized  New constructor that i create to pass value between form.

the problem i had is that, I am searching for a way that can allow me to un-hide form 2 from Form 3

without relying on the passing of object.
cause i ensure efficient use of computer memory for the code.
----------

however, as per  the solution link i posted. there seems to be no other solution unless i create object and pass by value.

thanks for your kind reply :)